# robust date and time formatting for calculations

Tags: excel, date, time, formatting, equation

I'm trying to format date and time data as it comes to me from a database to use for calculations.

Sample of data:
[image]

The instrument that the data is pulled from has operators enter sample dates and times by hand, and the software doesn't allow for special characters so everything is delimited by "."'s and " "'s. If you pair that with inconsistencies with number of characters (i.e. 0's before month, day, or hour), and use of AM and PM, it leads me to have to re-enter everything by hand for calculation purposes because things get so inconsistent.

The data flow is becoming heavier so the manual correction is becoming inefficient. Is there a robust set of equations I can use to format these entries and make them useful?

I know I can use the SUBSTITUTE function to get rid of the "."'s and " "'s, and if I can get the dates into a string of numbers

i.e 06.8.18 7.28 PM -> 0608181928

I could use a combination of the DATE, TIME, MOD, and TRUNC function to generate my dates and times. However, the inconsistency of number of characters and the need to correct for AM and PM is what throws me off.

Data with sample equations:
[image]

Comment: What output are you expecting for the dates? Can you please include the expected outcome from the formula?

Comment: Do you need the time component as well for your calculations?

Comment: @BruceWayne I'm expecting an out come of mm/dd/yy hh:mm (AM or PM) so my example above 0608181928 -> 06/08/18 07:28 PM

Comment: @Francis the time is an important component but I could use a =Date+Time formula to bring the two together in a separate column

Comment: Have you tried using tools like OpenRefine to see if it helps with the data cleansing process prior to importing to Excel? Could be a quick win

Comment: Also, per your previous comment, have you tried actually seperating into seperate date and time components first, and then recombing time after you've cleansed it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your time may have seconds, a forth `.` then this will do any number of `.`:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A2,FIND(" ",A2)-1),".","/")+SUBSTITUTE(MID(A2,FIND(" ",A2)+1,99),".",":")
```

Then apply the format desired:

[image]

Comment: Yes you could and skip the others, good thinking.  Feel free to answer and I will remove mine as that is better. @BigBen

Comment: this works for about 90% of cases however I do come into errors where there is an additional space between the date and time or lack of space between the time and the AM/PM

Comment: I got it working for all cases now. before I run your function I create 2 helper columns. the first one I use the TRIM function to remove additional spaces in the next one I use an if function to make sure that there is a space between every AM/PM   =IF( OR(RIGHT([@[helper 1]],3) = " PM",RIGHT([@[helper 1]],3) = " AM"),[@[helper 1]], CONCATENATE(LEFT([@[helper 1]],LEN([@[helper 1]])-2)," ",RIGHT([@[helper 1]],2))) and then your function does the rest. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a nested `SUBSTITUTE` to replace the 3rd period with a colon, then replace the remaining periods with slashes in an outer `SUBSTITUTE`. Then apply a custom format as needed.

`=--SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",":",3),".","/")`

[image]